# webdriver: unable to locate object (it works in IDE)

Tags: angularjs, selenium, ide, webdriver

I need some help :-) 
Basically, I have an input object (below) but I'm not able to locate it / insert any text  . It works normally with IDE, but not from my code (JAVA)

Code looks like:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("searchjobbyname")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("searchjobbyname")).sendKeys("job=123");
```

Object looks like:

```
 <input id="searchjobbyname" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" placeholder="Search job by name" data-ng-model="filterCtrl.filter.jobName" data-ng-change="filterCtrl.setJobName(filterCtrl.filter.jobName)" />
```

I also tried to locate it by class,css , etc. but the result is always the same. I have also other objects (data pickers) with the same problem
The are no frames and other stuff that might be problematic but, I noted that the  object is not located even when i check with firebug and this is very weird!

Comment: are you sure you are on the page you need to be, when executing this statement?   I've automated several AngularJS apps with Selenium with no issue, using commands very similar to yours.

Comment: Have you tried using `xpath`?

Comment: What is your implicit wait set to?  Webriver runs significantly faster than IDE so you may want to try cranking it up for a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shame on me :-) 
object is situated on an iFrame so driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@id='appIframe']"))) fixed the stuff

shame shame shameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee